# How can I design an activity with this apparence which work on any device with any resolution

Tags: android-layout, android-activity, android-widget, android-linearlayout, screen-resolution

I want to design a software which is work on any device with any screen-resolution.
would you help me?
I used **android:layout_weight** but it made me crazy

If you have any other suggestion, please tell me.

[image]
[image]

This is the XML code but is tooooo long.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".TTT">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="@string/Titre2"
            android:id="@+id/txtTitre2"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="false"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:textIsSelectable="false"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:id="@+id/textView"
            android:layout_below="@+id/txtTitre2"
            android:textSize="16sp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="3">

            <LinearLayout
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="1" >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/B0"
                        android:layout_row="0"
                        android:layout_column="0"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/B1"
                        android:layout_row="0"
                        android:layout_column="1"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/B2"
                        android:layout_row="0"
                        android:layout_column="2"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/B3"
                        android:layout_row="1"
                        android:layout_column="0"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/B4"
                        android:layout_row="1"
                        android:layout_column="1"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/B5"
                        android:layout_row="1"
                        android:layout_column="2"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>
                </LinearLayout>

                <LinearLayout
                    android:orientation="horizontal"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/B6"
                        android:layout_row="2"
                        android:layout_column="0"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/B7"
                        android:layout_row="2"
                        android:layout_column="1"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>

                    <Button
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="match_parent"
                        android:id="@+id/B8"
                        android:layout_row="2"
                        android:layout_column="2"
                        android:layout_weight="1"/>
                </LinearLayout>

            </LinearLayout>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="Small Text"
                android:id="@+id/textView5"
                android:layout_weight="2"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:id="@+id/textView7"
            android:text="12121212"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                android:text="Small Text"
                android:id="@+id/textView6" />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/New"
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_row="4"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:onClick="newGame" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
            android:text="Small Text"
            android:id="@+id/textView8"
            android:layout_weight="3" />

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.
When we use **android:layout_weight=Value** we should set the value of **android:layout_weight** to **0dp** if we use **vertical linearlayout** and 

if we use **horizontal linearlayout** we should set the value of ***android:layout_height*** to **0dp**
The value of six layout in top should be 1, 1, 3, 1, 1 ,3 respectively.

And for having a distance of 40% from left in 5th layout, we should define it like vertical linearLayout and set the weight of first TextView which is empty to 2 and button 3 and the last Empty TextView 1

I put the XML code which is necessairy

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3">
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3" />

</LinearLayout>
```